# Basic Encryption random function

Tags: java, encryption, random

Hi I am writing a code in java for an encryption! its on a whole new algorithm itself. I had this idea about its algorithm while I was solving a math problem in a lecture at college. So basically there are two functions that encrypt the string using different techniques but to make it a little more complex I wanted the program to be able to choose on between the two functions completely randomly

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: because times two makes the algorithm soooo much more complex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
Type result = Math.random()*2 > 1 ? myAFunction() : myBFunction();
```